# Find a subsequence of an array of tuples using regex

Tags: java, python, regex

Lets assume that I have the following array of string tuples:

```
[N][F][N][N,F],[F,NN,FN,...][N,F],[F,NB,NN,..]
```

I want to find a sublist that the first tuple contains `N` and the second one contains `F`.

Here  are the excepted answers:

```
    [N][F]
    [N][N,F]
    [N,F],[F,NN,FN]
    [N,F],[F,NB,NN]
```

I've tried this

```
(\[N\])(\[F\])
```

So it can detect `[N][F]`, But with it only works where tuples has only one element.

Is it possible to achieve this using regex?

Comment: btw: this looks more like you should loop through your array with java and just match for N resp. F

Comment: what is with the "tuples" that are actually triples?

Comment: To clarify: do you have an array of string tuples, or do you have a single string which contains brackets and *represents* an array of tuples?

Comment: @RealSkeptic it's a single string that looks like an array of tuples

Comment: @Fallenhero tuples are [ordered lists of elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple). 2-tuple is a couple, 3-tuple is a triple, 4-tuple is a quadruple.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: ah you are right

Comment: Is the criterion for 'N' _starts_ with N, or _contains_ N? What about [F,N][F] - would that be a match?

Comment: @subrunner yes it would be match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and based on your try:

```
\[[^\]]*N[^\]]*\][^\]]*F[^\]]*\]
```

this should work for you.

See: https://regex101.com/r/HQ3WAA/4

Comment: I updated the answer, please check if this is that you expect